# Opening a new SSH Terminal through Browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ssh, browser

I have SSH IP address.

Is it possible to open a SSH terminal through browser? (Just like a hyperlink or a Google Play store Link?)

For example: ***Click Here to Open SSH Terminal***

**And this should open the SSH** and the user will be asked to prompt username/password.

Thanks,
- R

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne

It's HTML5 based, so no plugins and security problems.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to launch an installed APP on your Computer through a link.
If you are in Windows and you want this to work just for you, use ActiveXObject and WScript which are supported by IE only.

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/430857/how-to-launch-a-window-application-exe-from-a-web

Vor you could add a registry key to create your own application url, that you can use later in your Website.

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/71831-application-url-launch-local-application-from-browser/